# How to install a TFS vNext build agent on Mac?

Tags: macos, tfs

Is this even able to do this? We are going to deploy a build agent on our test Mac Machine with mac OS.

My customer told me it's a cross-platform product.

Which necessary programs do I need to install on my mac OS? I am not a Mac user,it is hard to directly find the things I need.

Comment: Where are you problems with it? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a thoroughly tutorial: [**Deploy an agent on OSX**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-osx) in official. You need the latest version of **OpenSLL**.The VSTS Agent uses the OpenSSL library to connect securely to VSTS/TFS.

> **Check prerequisites**
>
> Make sure your machine is prepared with our [OSX system
>   prerequisites](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/blob/master/docs/start/envosx.md).

In order to use .NET Core, we first need the latest version of OpenSSL. The easiest way to get this is from [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). After installing brew, do the following:

```
brew update
brew install openssl
# Ensure folder exists on machine
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

More details please refer below related issue:

- [Failed to connect" v2.99.0 on OSX](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/110)
- [Installing a VSTS Build agent on Mac OSX](https://roadtoalm.com/2017/02/13/installing-a-vsts-build-agent-on-mac-osx/)

Comment: Thanks, copy that. Anything else do I need to install on MAC OSX for TFS build. We usually need to install VS on our build agent in many cases. Have any experience of this sort of thing on MAC OSX?

Comment: @NewBalance Just as *Greaka* said in comment. It's based on your environment and your customer. If you are lacking of some components when you trigger the build. You will got some prompting message as build error in the logs. It's better to make sure you are using the same environment on the build agent and local.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/releases and download the OSX release. After that, unpack and start

```
~/$ mkdir myagent && cd myagent
~/myagent$ tar xzf ~/Downloads/vsts-agent-osx.<osversion>-x64-<agent-version>.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks Greaka, have tried that command. Is there some limitation of the Mac OS or network environment? Got the error `The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.CurlHandler' threw an exception.
Failed to connect. `

Comment: That could propably be worth another question. Did you install all necessary programs on the machine? PS: If my question solved your problem, be free to mark it as the solution ;)

Comment: Thanks again, maybe I'm not making myself clear. Which necessary programs do I need to install on my mac OS? This is the actually question which I was asking. I am not a Mac user, it is hard to directly find the things I need. I thinks it's also belong to the installation.

Comment: TFS is self containing. For any other program needed, you have to ask your customer which programs are needed in the build process. The build definition should tell you all informations you need.